# Extracting AWS AZ from Hostname

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to figure out how to extract the availability zone (AZ) from an AWS hostname, using Python.  I know how to extract the start or end of a hostname, but not the middle.  Example:

```
ec2-1-1-1-1.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com.
ec2-2-2-2-2.us-gov-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com.
ec2-3-3-3-3.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com.
```

For those not familiar with AWS, the AZ is middle part of the hostname "us-west-2", "us-gov-west-1", "ap-southeast-2".  The format is consistent across regions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI `us-west-2` is a region. It has 3 availability zones (A, B, C). Other regions have different number of availability zones. But, you're referring to regions, not AZs.

Comment: Yes, good point.  I would need to compare this to AWS's IP API.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple regex for picking your intended name.

```
^[^.]+\.([^.]+)
```

for capturing AZ name, you need to capture group 1 text.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EyZFHh/2)

Python code that extracts the names,

```
import re
arr = ['ec2-1-1-1-1.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com.','ec2-2-2-2-2.us-gov-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com.','ec2-3-3-3-3.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com.']
for s in arr:
 match = re.search(r'^[^.]+\.([^.]+)', s)
 print (s + ' --> ' + match.group(1))
```

Here is the output,

```
ec2-1-1-1-1.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com. --> us-west-2
ec2-2-2-2-2.us-gov-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com. --> us-gov-west-1
ec2-3-3-3-3.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com. --> ap-southeast-2
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Pushpesh

Comment: @Ethan: Glad to help :) Let me know if you face any trouble in any of your case.

Comment: @Ethan: If my answer works well for you, please mark it as accepted answer, so future googlers looking for a solution to this kind of problem can easily reach this answer and get benefited from.